# Predis\Connection\ConnectionException error in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, redis

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6037]

this is my env code redis

```
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=9999
```

got this error while developing in laravel. I was not even using redis. tried changing the port but still no luck ,

tried installing redis as per the suggestions provided on stack overflow but still no luck

tried clearing cache and restarting server , still no luck

any ideas how to solve the problem ??
any help will pe appreciated

Comment: In your env file, do you have any place where redis is in there? most often cache driver or session?

Comment: Check if redis has been started

Answer (score 0):

you should change the .env value for "CACHE_DRIVER=redis" and dont forget to clear config like `php artisan config:clear`